# Is there a VPN tunnel service that doesnt require installing anything on my Computer?

Tags: vpn, osx-lion, tunnel

I am look for a VPN tunnel that is free and that I can just configure into my System Preferences (Mac OS X Lion). Anybody know of such a service?

Comment: You're not likely going to find a free one. There are reasonably-priced ones, though.

Comment: Why would anybody offer such a service for free? I wouldn't trust or rely on it. You get what you pay for.

Comment: Can you clarify?  Does the answer by @TheCompWiz answer the question?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

VPN clients are built natively into OSX, (System Preferences -> Network, click the +, and add a VPN connection)... VPN Servers on the other hand are not so simple.  OSX Lion Server does offer a VPN server option that you can setup & manage through the "Server App"... but if you don't have lion server, your options are to resort to 3rd party tools and/or services.  There are some tricks you can do to setup a vpn server (at least in [snow-leopard](http://hints.macworld.com/article.php?story=20060616150640529)) but I'm not sure they work in Lion.

Answer (score 0):

I din't know exactly what you are trying to achieve but there is the possibility of using [back to my Mac](http://support.apple.com/kb/ht1109).

You will need to set find my iPhone and find my Mac up through iCloud.  They work together (Back to my Mac and ICloud).

Comment: Could you link to a manual?